# Can the data of an Apple Keynote chart be changed from AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, keynote

I would like to write a script to generate a keynote presentation to animate a data set on a chart by building one slide per change in the data.

The starting point would be a keynote presentation containing a single slide which contains a chart, this will be the template.

The script would then duplicate that template slide for each data change and update the data of the chart to display the new values.

The template and duplication is all fine but I cannot find a way **change** the backing data of the chart. There is an AppleScript **add chart** action but that would require hard coding all of the design elements of the chart into the script. I would much prefer to edit the chart visually in KeyNote and have the script use that as a template.

So, the question is: Is there any way to change the backing data of a KeyNote chart from AppleScript?

I have tried the following and many similar permutations:

> set the data of chart 1 to ({45, 25})